# converting a PC into virtual mobile

Tags: mobile, virtual, simulator

This might be a stupid question. Although, anyone of you know about a software or any technique so i can use my mobile services on my pc in similar way i do on mobile.

Like calling, sending sms, watching TV, running games, net surfing, FM etc

I am having android. But I'll appreciate if you suggest something works of every mobile.

Comment: One of the simulator i found is androidlive(code.google.com/p/live-android) But it doesnt let me connect & work on my own mobile instead of virtual mobile

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could get Android x86 to run your computer from a USB stick.